# Get my IP in localhost server

Tags: php, xampp

I want to know if I could get my own IP in localhost.

I've tried to use `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` but it displays `127.0.0.1`, I don't want to get that, I just want to get my own IP not `127.0.0.1`, it works if I use other computers and connect to my `localhost` site via the same internet.. and it gave me their real ip address that it should get, but for me `host[er]` I get `127.0.0.1`. I want to test it on a localhost server.

Let me explain it:

My IP for example is `11.77.662.88` and I connect to my site, and it displays my IP, I want it to display `11.77.662.88` not `127.0.0.1`

That said I tried a lot of methods not just `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` but all of it gave me the same result.

I just want to make sure everything goes alright in localhost server before I publish it on a hosting server.. I searched for it a lot but didn't find the best answer for my needs.. I'm still searching, hope someone can help me with this cause I couldn't find the right answer + I know that I have multiple IP address, but how can i get one of them? I know `127.0.0.1` is my own IP, but how can I get the IP that's for example in IP Chicken? and as I said for example my IP is `11.77.662.88` I want to get that, but how?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` **is** your own IP. You have multiple IP addresses and the loopback IP is one of them.

Comment: @ppeterka also i don't want to get it on any hosting whether it's free or not, i want to test everything on localhost, i don't want any kind of hosting until i'm done with my project, I tried to use free hosting, and got the ip address that i need, but there is some problems with it, not running the code that's needed to be executed, and every single **free** hosting does the same thing, cause i've tried a lot..

Comment: Then if it works why do you ask? Also, localhost is just like that. It is like going home when you are already home: do you go out to the front lawn, turn back, and go back inside the house? I think no. Neither does your computer: if the client and server are the same machine, it will use the shorter path. It won't go the extra trouble of actually going out to the  Internet when the target is itself... Time to read up on how a network stack works.

Comment: So you'r saying that there is no way of doing that?

Comment: Well, I think the subject isn't worth the trouble: the only problem you'll see is when the client runs on the same machine - which is not likely...

Comment: it will always be ::1 no matter what, if you want to test your script the supports this functionality use a free host

Answer (score 0):

Searched and never found the right answer..

@ppeterka said

> Then if it works why do you ask? Also, localhost is just like that. It is like going home when you are already home: do you go out to the front lawn, turn back, and go back inside the house? I think no. Neither does your computer: if the client and server are the same machine, it will use the shorter path. It won't go the extra trouble of actually going out to the Internet when the target is itself... Time to read up on how a network stack works.

And He/She has a point for that, i think it's right.. In the end you'll just have to get a `free` hosting for testing.. but for me `free` hosting, doesn't do much, cause there is features that are disabled, overall i think i can put $myIp for faking my ip in the site **FOR TESTING**, until i get everything right. :D

**Thanks For the help**

> Edit

Alternative way to get your IP address on localhost is using api's such as ipify it's really helpful to use it when you actually need it, since every free web hosting block exec() and some other functions/classes for php, and that's the main reason i'm avoiding free web hosting

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Developer here,

Hi, you can try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. It is obtained from the [HTTP Request Header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) and it returns the IP address of your server.

Comment: I don't want the ip address of the server, Let's say for example i configured my xampp vhosts from localhost to **example.com**.. So i connect to it, i'll see **example.com** not **215.56.23.155**..

Answer (score 0):

PHP < 5.3.0

```
$localIP = getHostByName(php_uname('n'));
```

PHP >= 5.3.0

```
$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());
```

From bro @andras-tim